# WMS filter/aggregator for GetCapabilities

Tags: wms, filter, aggregation, getcapabilities

I have a GUI that consumes WMS layers.  We want to be able to connect to multiple WMS services, but we don't want the users seeing all the available layers, just the ones that are relevant for our use case.

I was planning to write a utility service that would allow us to connect to multiple servers, call GetCapabilities on them, and then allow us to choose which layers to provide to our GUI.

The GUI would then call GetCapabilities on the utility and only get the filtered responses back.

Before I do that I thought I'd ask if anyone knows of something similar (preferably FOSS) that might already exist.  I've done some searching already, but haven't found exactly what I'm looking for...

Comment: Using WMS services as a datasource by another WMS service is the way to go (cascading).  Various opensource software allow this such as MapServer, GeoServer, and deegree

Answer (score 1):

GeoServer can [cascade external WMS services](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/cascaded/wms.html) and you can chose which layers to publish in each case.